# Why is the default Ubuntu swappiness 60?

Tags: swap

What is the reasoning for Ubuntu's default swappiness being 60?

Comment: Same or similar? http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/88693/why-is-swappiness-set-to-60-by-default